# Is there any module I can use in python to calculate like how i use T.INV.2T in excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, math, formula

I want to calculate this excel formula in Python : T.INV.2T(1-D25;9999999999). The result in excel is : 2,57582940

is there any package or example in Python I can try to calculate this formula? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy import stats

alfa = 0.005
free_deg = 9999999999
print('stat: ', stats.t.ppf(1-alfa, free_deg))

#stat:  2.575829304040555
```

Follow https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html#scipy.stats.t

```
ppf(q, df, loc=0, scale=1) 
#Percent point function (inverse of cdf — percentiles).
```

Comment: please add some context explaining your answer so we can learn; it otherwise will be down-voted and removed due a lack of it.

Comment: why does it need to be 0.005?

Comment: Doesnt need to be 0.005. Just change alfa value that suits You.